# Inserting a character into a string in NASM

Tags: string, assembly, character, nasm

I'm trying to do a very simple assembly exercise with NASM, but the everything I've been taught suggests this should work, yet it doesn't.

It's supposed to iterate through the string "Burning The Midnight Oil," and place the characters into *dest* in reverse, so that it prints "liO thgindiM ehT gninruB" to the output. It does not. It just prints the string of x's, no matter what I do to change it.

What am I missing here? How can I edit the contents of *dest* after I create it? I am so tired.

```
global _start
section .text
_start: mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, dest
        mov rdx, len
        syscall
        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall
section .data
src:    db 'Burning The Midnight Oil', 10
dest:   db 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 10
len:    equ $ - dest

        xor rcx,rcx
        mov rcx,len
        mov rsi,len
loopstart:
        sub rsi,rcx
        mov al,[src+rcx]
        mov [dest+rsi],al
        dec rcx
        jnz loopstart
```

Comment: You display and exit even before processing the string!. Move the loop code at *_start:*.

Comment: ...Oh, dear god. It was genuinely that simple???? It prints "liO thgindiM ehT gninruB" now. Thank you so much. I feel a bit silly, but I also feel like my professor shouldn't wait until finals week to start teaching us assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program starts executing at the *_start* label. You immediately display and exit even before processing the string! Move the loop code at *_start:*.

Your `len: equ $ - dest` includes the newline code (10). That's wrong! You must leave that byte where it is.

```
len:    equ ($ - dest) - 1   ; Iteration count
```

Writing to the last position of the string requires using "Length - 1", therefore write `mov [dest+rsi-1], al`

Copying the string just requires using two offsets: one incrementing and the other decrementing until zero:

```
_start:
    mov  rdi, len
    xor  esi, esi
loopstart:
    mov  al, [src + rsi]
    mov  [dest + rdi - 1], al
    dec  rdi
    jnz  loopstart

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, dest
    mov rdx, len
    syscall
    mov rax, 60
    xor edi, edi
    syscall
```

Comment: I used that approach in an earlier version of the code- it returned an "error: invalid effective address" at the time. Your code seems to work now, for some reason, but the main problem remains: It still only outputs a string of x's.